# retrieving data from openweather api in angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I get an object from openweather api which has an array of 40 objects with weather forecast for 5 days with 3 hours interval. I have problem to display this 5 day forecast in my angular 2 app. I need to filter this data by days and display these 5 days forecast in the angular template, display date, day, forecast. I attached screenshot of the object that I get from openweather api
[image]

This my ts file code that gets this object:

```
 this.weatherService.loadCFiveDay(data.lat, data.lon)
                  .subscribe(data=>{                   

                      data.list.forEach(item => {
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a pipe for this to loop by date:

```
@Pipe({
    name : 'filterByDate',
    pure : false
})

export class FilterByDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items : any[], filterDate : number) : any {
        if (!items || !items.length || !filterDate)
            return items;

        return items.filter(item => new Date(item.dt).getDate() === filterDate);
    }
}
```

Then in your view, do something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let filteredDate of myServiceData.list | filterByDate:22">
   <!-- everything here will now be filtered by the date of 22nd, so you can do things like -->
   <p>Today's weather - <span>{{ filteredDate.weather[0].description }}</span></p>
</div>
```

There probably is a more elegant way, but this should get you started.

Comment: this is a bit not what I need. I need to display in the template all info that each of 40 objects has: date(dt), clouds, weather(which has object inside). I updated screen, you can what I mean. Thank you

Comment: you can display it all.  This filters the _object_, not just the individual property.  For example, in the above, filteredDate would show each object in the list that has the list[x].dt date match.  I did make a small error, which I'll fix though, and maybe it'll make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

get the current coords:

```
getCurrentLocation() {
  return new Observable<GeolocationCoordinates>((observer) => {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        observer.next(position.coords);
        observer.complete();
      },
      (err) => observer.error(err)
    );
  }).pipe(
    retry(1),
    tap(
      () => {
        this.notificationsService.addSuccess('Got your location');
      }
    ),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.notificationsService.addError('failed to get your location');
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}
```

Then make http request to get the data and process the incoming data

```
interface OpenWeatherResponse {
  list: {
    dt_txt: string;
    main: {
      temp: number;
    };
  }[];
}

getForecast() {
    return this.getCurrentLocation().pipe(
      //  map will transfor the value into http params which is built into angular
      map((coords) => {
        return new HttpParams()
          .set('lat', String(coords.latitude))
          .set('lon', String(coords.longitude))
          .set('units', 'metric')
          .set('appid', 'a0e7bb8efb3c2da48a50b39af7cf0038');
      }),
      // whenever switch map gets a new value, it will delete the old observable. that is the only difference between switchMap and mergeMap
      // when googling "why", googe does not  make  request for "w","h""y". that is wasteful. it cancels "w","h"
      // inorder to use http module we need to import HTTPModule into app module
      // making requests also returns observable
      switchMap((params) =>
        this.http.get<OpenWeatherResponse>(this.url, { params })
      ),
      // pull of the "list" object
      pluck('list'),
      // we want to pick 8 of 40 objects. mergeMap returns an observable which rather than emitting the array of objects , it will take every object and emit it one by one
      // the goal is to take the array of recods and break it up into a consistent stream of records instead
      // use mergeMap instead of switch map becase we dont want to cancel other objects
      mergeMap((value) => of(...value)), // of emits everyhing one-by-one
      // we are getting 5 day print-out. we get 8 records of 3 hours intervals. total is 40. we dont need . at most we need every 8 object. 
      filter((value, index) => index % 8 === 0),
      map((value) => {
        return {
          dateString: value.dt_txt,
          temp: value.main.temp,
        };
      }),
      // turn this to an array so u can use *ngFor directive inside .html
      toArray(),

      share()
    );
  }
```